# Why every time I try to enter my publisher name my npm says I need to view user permissions on it?

Tags: npm, cmd, visual-studio-code, themes, command-line-interface

The present reason I'm asking this question is that my npm CLI server in the Command Prompt doesn't let me register my theme to the Visual Studio Code Marketplace. I did as the VS Code website's tutorial on how to publish an extension read. However, when I typed my Personal Access Token in the cmd as it was shown to me, this is what I get:

```
>vsce login 'my publisher name'
#Error: Access Denied: 'Username' needs the following permission(s) on
#the resource /publisher name to perform this action: View user permissions
#on a resource
```

I tried several times, and even gave it full access to all accessible organizations in my Azure DevOps. And for your information, my computer runs on Windows 8.1.

This is the package.json file I tried to register:

```
{
"name": "blacklady-code-workspace",
"displayName": "Black Lady Theme",
"description": "Modeled after the Black Lady from Sailor Moon R.",
"version": "0.0.1",
"publisher": "ayaimarion",
"repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ZanJang/blacklady-theme-ver-0.0.1"
},
"engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.30.0"
},
"categories": [
    "Themes"
],
"contributes": {
    "themes": [
        {
            "label": "Black Lady",
            "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
            "path": "./themes/Black Lady-color-theme.json"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

If there's something I did do wrong, let me know.

My Azure DevOps organization: https://dev.azure.com/ayamaki

Comment: Now it is ok. Let us remove our, now obsolete comments.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I had not yet created the publisher in the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/).

Once I created the new publisher, the `vsce login` command succeeded.

Comment: How do you create a publisher in the VS Code Marketplace?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-publishing-a-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2017